# MySQL search with uft8_general_ci is case sensitive for FULLTEXT?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation, case-sensitive, full-text-search

I set up a MyISAM table to do FULLTEXT searching.
I **do not** want searches to be case-sensitive.

My searches are along the lines of:

SELECT * FROM search WHERE MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ('+diversity +kitten' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Let's say the keywords field I'm looking for has the value "my Diversity kitten".

I noticed the searches were case-sensitive.
I double-checked my collation on the search table, it was set to **utf8_bin**.  D'oh!
I changed it to **utf8_general_ci**.

But my query is still case-sensitive!
Why?

Is there a server setting I need to change, too?

Is there something I need to do besides change the collation?

I did a "REPAIR TABLE search QUICK" to rebuild the FULLTEXT index, but that didn't do it either...

My searches are still case-sensitive. =(

Comment: The table may be utf8_general_ci, but are the columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha, figured it out for reals this time.

I believe my issue was using NaviCat to update the collation.  I have an older version of NaviCat, maybe it was a bug or something.

Doing:

ALTER TABLE search CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

fixed it correctly.

Always use command line, kids!  =)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm - that behavior doesn't match the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> By default, the search is performed in
>   case-insensitive fashion. However, you
>   can perform a case-sensitive full-text
>   search by using a binary collation for
>   the indexed columns. For example, a
>   column that uses the `latin1` character
>   set of can be assigned a collation of
>   `latin1_bin` to make it case sensitive
>   for full-text searches.

Which version of MySQL do you use? Can you provide some data that would allow replicating the problem on another machine?